# How to get the sum of the last 15 values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, slice

So I'm slicing my timeseries data, but for some of the columns, I need to be able to have the sum of the elements the were sliced. For example if you had

```
s = pd.Series([10, 30, 21, 18])
s = s[::-2]
```

I need to get the sum of a range of elements in this situation so I would need

```
3   39
1   40
```

as the output. I've see things like .cumsum() but I can't find anything to sum a range of elements

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand what's the first column represent. But the second column seems to be the sum result.

If you have got the correct slice, it's easy to get `sum` with `sum()`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(0, 10).reshape(-1, 2)
pd.DataFrame(data).iloc[2:].sum(axis=1)
```

Output is :

> 2     9
> 3    13
> 4    17
> dtype: int64

Answer (score 0):

The answer based only in your title would be `df[-15:].sum()`, but it seems you're looking for performing a calculation per group of slicing.

To address this problem, pandas provides the [window utilities](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html). So, you can simply do:

```
s = pd.Series([10, 30, 21, 18])
s.rolling(2).sum()[::-2].astype(int)
```

which returns:

```
3    39
1    40
dtype: int64
```

Also, it's escalable, once you can replace `2` by any other value, and the `.rolling` method also works in dataframe objects.